# Android Firefox 38 pageWorker don't work

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I develop an extension for mobile version (as Android version) of Firefox borwser. I use [sdk/page-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker) high-level api for create a background page for connect with WebSocket server. But when I updated my Firefox to 38 version, page-worker dont'work!
In example I have a next source:

```
var pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker");
var tmp = pageWorker.Page({
     contentScript: 'console.log("Im loaded!!");'
});
```

It was work on older version of Firefox (etc 37).

But it don't work only in mobile version of Firefox. On desktop Firefox 38 page-worker is work.

It's a bug or a new feature? Thanks!